# Silverstripe Gridfield Extensions - TextFields are shown as Textarea

Tags: silverstripe

Perhaps someone can help me. I've just installed the Grid Field Extensions Module for Silverstripe (https://github.com/ajshort/silverstripe-gridfieldextensions) because I need inline editing/adding. It works, but simple TextFields are shown as textareas and not as a simple textfield.

Can someone tell me how to change that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The module attempts to automatically work out what field would be best for your variable. It will create a `DropdownField` for an `Enum` variable, `TextareaField` for a `Text` varialbe and so on.

If you don't want to manually set the field types for each variable that you want to be editable inline you need to change your variables a little.

`TextareaField` is the field set for `Text` variables.

`TextField` is the field set for `Varchar` variables.

For any variables that you want to be a `TextField` instead of a `TextareaField` change it's type from `Text` to `Varchar(255)` (or however large a character limit you need).

Otherwise you can manually set the fields using 
`setDisplayFields` as described in the [documentation](https://github.com/ajshort/silverstripe-gridfieldextensions/blob/master/docs/en/index.md).

```
$grid->getConfig()->getComponentByType('GridFieldEditableColumns')->setDisplayFields(array(
    'FirstField'  => function($record, $column, $grid) {
        return new TextField($column);
    }, 
    'SecondField'  => function($record, $column, $grid) {
        return new TextField($column);
    }, 
    // ... etc for each field you want to be editable
));
```

Comment: I already tried this.
But than the stored content of the records created before are not shown. Also only 1 Field is shown and I can't add new records

Comment: @cSGermany - In future, please mention in your question what you have tried and why it didn't work. It will save time for people trying to help.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show how to automatically have TextField come up instead of TextareaField. I have also expanded on the manual solution. I've tested the manual solution and found it did not change whether I could add new records. Note, if you set the fields manually you need to declared each field, not just the one you want to change.